# How to allow user to click the button on time then disable the button click? (Laravel 8)

Tags: mysql, laravel, function, button, controller

I have Laravel project (voting system) that will allow the user to vote for forms

my question here is, how can i prevent the user from voting more than once for each form?

here is the user database:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('student_id');
        $table->string('student_faculity');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('usertype')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and here is the forms table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('file_path')->nullable();
        $table->string('name_as_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->string('position')->nullable();
        $table->text('bio')->nullable();
        $table->string('approve')->nullable();
        $table->string('votes')->default('0');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

forms balde (vote button):

```
<form method="post" id="my-form" action="{{ route('votes.upVote', $row->id) }}">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input id="btn-submit" class="" name="submitbutton" value="Vote" type="submit">
    </form>
```

"I'm using foreach loop to display all forms"

forms controller (vote function):

```
public function upVote(Request $request, $id)
{
    File::find($id)->increment('votes', 1);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

is there a way that i can prevent the user from spamming the vote button?

note: the user can vote once for each form so the vote button won't be disabled for other forms if the user voted for a specific form

what is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you could upload a specific `form_id` entry against a `user_id` and then in your blade file inside `foreach` just evaluate if that entry exists or not. If it does so disable else enable.

Comment: do you mean passing the id of a user to form table?

Comment: Right. But you also need form_id to validate against a particular form and not disable rest of the forms.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery You can disable submit button after submit form

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(){
   $('#btn-submit').attr('disabled', true);
})
```

Comment: this won't work if the user refresh the page

Comment: Then you need to create pivot file_votes table with file_id and user_id.... Then you can detect if user already voted, disallow vote function for him...